# Global variable used in object property not updating inside the object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object set up like so:

```
let xVal = 0;

const myObj = {
  infoText: "The value of x is: " + xVal
}
```

This infoText is referenced later to display somewhat of a tooltip when hovering over an element.

```
function showTooltip(obj) {
  targetEl = document.getElementById('targetId');
  targetEl.innerHTML = obj.infoText;
}
```

The value of xVal can change. The issue I'm running into is that despite whether or not that value has changed, when I hover over my element, it will always display the initial value of xVal. I assume this is because myObj.infoText is established when it's initiated and pulls the initial value of xVal. How can I get myObj.infoText to show the current xVal and keep up with the changes?

EDIT - Here is a better example of my code, I realize I offered a poor sample originally.

```
let count = 0;
let clickVal = 1;

const myObj = {
  cost: 10,
  infoText: `This displays the current value of your click <br />
  Current click = ` + clickVal
};

function cardContent(obj) {
  targetEl = document.getElementById('targetId');
  targetEl.innerHTML = obj.infoText;
}
cardContent(myObj); // initialize card content

function handleClick() {
  count += clickVal;
}

function upgradeClick() {
  count -= myObj.cost;
  clickVal += 1;
  cardContent(myObj) // attempting to update the text to reflect new value
}
```

There is a button that invokes `handleClick` and one that invokes `upgradeClick`. Using CSS, the following `div` is hidden and shows when hovering over the `upgradeClick` button.
`<div id='targetId'></div>` This is where the `infoText` shows.

Comment: How is `showTooltip` called, and how is `myObj` changing? You should produce a [mcve] and update your question with it.

Comment: Apologies, `showToolTip` is called immediately when the page loads, and then again within a function that is invoked on an onClick event.
`myObj` contains other numeric properties that are changing, but any reference to those works properly. I'll update my original post with a more useful code example.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO btw. In future you might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I appreciate your kindness! I'll check out the linked material, thanks so much for providing the info!

Comment: Happy coding, @Chilli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like a getter

```js
let xVal = 0;

const myObj = {
  get infoText() {return "The value of x is: " + xVal;}
}

function showTooltip(obj) {
  console.log(obj.infoText);
}

showTooltip(myObj);
xVal = 29;
showTooltip(myObj);
xVal = 794;
showTooltip(myObj);
```

Comment: This solved it perfectly. I was not familiar with getters, but this is exactly what I needed to ensure I was grabbing the current xVal every time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Creating the object everytime inside of the showTooltip should work

```js
let xVal = 0;

function showTooltip() {
    const myObj = {
        infoText: "The value of x is: " + xVal
    }
    console.log(myObj.infoText);
}

showTooltip();
xVal = 50;
showTooltip();
```